# How to apply cron jobs to Api methods that requires authntication?

Tags: api, twitter, cron, youtube-api, instagram-api

Hello frinds presently i am doing manually authentication and getting  user tweets and post form various api like instagram,tweeter,youtube but it requires authentication .

Now i want to automate the process and wish to run cron so i can fetch data every hour with authentication.

I know it is possible by passing access token in url methods but no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to have those access tokens. I'll explain the YouTube API and will also write other API's links. Process is similar in almost every API first you get the token then you pass it in URL.

**YouTube API :**

Here is a [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) about YouTube API which will help you create your own access key. After creating it just pass the key in URL with `key=YOUR_API_KEY`. You can retrieve datas from these links they might also give you an idea about how to use the api key : [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) , [Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)  (There are examples in the documents for JAVA, PHP and Python ). If you are using PHP you can use this [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) function for authentication and retrieving datas.